# I have two tables in a SQL database, need to get data based on group by from one table and other in normal

Tags: sql

table 1: decks

| deckid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1662490522316 | test1 |
| 1662975567468 | test3 |
| 1663153348829 | test4/@/4 |
| 1664289454461 | Science Class EBP Physics 9th |
| 1665037005819 | d/@/dog |

table 2: cards

| cardid | noteid | deckid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1635883239955 | 1635883239955 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883239956 | 1635883239955 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883343194 | 1635883343194 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883343195 | 1635883343194 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883382043 | 1635883382043 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883382044 | 1635883382043 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883439273 | 1635883439273 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883439274 | 1635883439273 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883509673 | 1635883509673 | 1664289454461 |
| 1635883509674 | 1635883509673 | 1664289454461 |
| 1662490587893 | 1662490587892 | 1662490522316 |
| 1662491389237 | 1662491389237 | 1662490522316 |
| 1662491433306 | 1662491433306 | 1662490522316 |
| 1662886491604 | 1662886491600 | 1662490522316 |
| 1662886955205 | 1662886955203 | 1662490522316 |
| 1662965836930 | 1662965836929 | 1662490522316 |
| 1663129181833 | 1663129181832 | 1662975567468 |
| 1663675409308 | 1663675409308 | 1663153348829 |
| 1663675409309 | 1663675409308 | 1663153348829 |
| 1663728830758 | 1663728830757 | 1662975567468 |
| 1664353381308 | 1664353381307 | 1662490522316 |
| 1664358364077 | 1664358364074 | 1662490522316 |
| 1664358364078 | 1664358364075 | 1662490522316 |
| 1665037065057 | 1665037065047 | 1665037005819 |

i want a query to return deckid, name and count of cards. for each decks
each deck will have n number of cards which is shown in table 2: cards

I
did that with two queries
1)

```
SELECT decks.deckid, decks.name FROM decks
```

which returns

| deckid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1662490522316 | test1 |
| 1662975567468 | test3 |
| 1663153348829 | test4/@/4 |
| 1664289454461 | Science Class EBP Physics 9th |
| 1665037005819 | d/@/dog |

2)

```
SELECT cards.deckid, count(cards.deckid) 
FROM cards 
GROUP BY cards.deckid
```

which returns number(or)count of cards in one deck id

| deckid | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1662490522316 | 9 |
| 1662975567468 | 2 |
| 1663153348829 | 2 |
| 1664289454461 | 10 |
| 1665037005819 | 1 |

i am expecting a query which returns this two result in to one like.

| deckid | name | count(crad.cardid) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1662490522316 | test1 | 9 |
| 1662975567468 | test3 | 2 |
| 1663153348829 | test4/@/4 | 2 |
| 1664289454461 | Science Class EBP Physics 9th | 10 |
| 1665037005819 | d/@/dog | 1 |

Comment: You are looking for a [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html)

Comment: There is no question here. PS Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] PS Please do not tell volunteers what you "need" & "want" & "expect". Say what you are trying to do & what you have done & how you are stuck. PS Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please read & apply the edit help re inline & block formats for code, etc.

Comment: tried join but dint worked

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can link tables with `JOIN` if one to one, `LEFT JOIN` if one to many.

```
select d.deckid, d.name, COUNT(c.cardid) 
from
deck d 
left join cards c on c.deckid = d.deckid
group by
d.deckid, d.name
```

Comment: c.deckid has duplicate deckids will it work?

Comment: @Ranjithkumar deckid works as a link field and we count the number of rows in the table cards for each deck record.

Comment: tried the above query didn't worked.

Comment: @Ranjithkumar what's wrong? what database?

Comment: sqlite3, 
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such collation sequence: unicase

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT decks.deckid, decks.name, count(cards.cardid)
from decks
JOIN cards
ON decks.deckid = cards.deckid
GROUP BY cards.deckid
```

This one worked.